# Unconfirmed transaction: does the receiver know about it?

Tags: unconfirmed-transactions

I just sent someone some bitcoins, but it's still at the unconfirmed transaction stage.  But does the receiver know this information yet, i.e., that I have sent and we are merely waiting for it to go through?

Answer (score 1):

depends on the software. yes, the receiver **is able** to know this information